# Deriving a method of solving Pursuit curves

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am currently studying ODEs and became interested in pursuit curves. However I am having trouble simplifying the equations into solvable DEs. Here is my work:

If mouse (m) moves along a curve then cat (c) describes the pursuit curve which minimises the path following the movement of the mouse. In the following problem for simplicity the cat’s velocity (c’) will equal 1 and be parallel to m-c. Thus, these equation are formed.

$$m=\langle u(t),v(t)\rangle ,c=\langle x(t),y(t)\rangle$$

$$\frac{m-c}{   \|  m-c\| }   .  \frac{c}{ \|  c\| } = \frac{(u-x) x' +(v-y) y' }{ \sqrt{(u-x)^{2}+(v-y)^{2}} } =1$$
$$ (x')^{2}+(y')^2 =1$$
Manipulating the first equation yields the following
$$ (u-x)x'+(v-y)y'=\sqrt{(u-x)^{2}+(v-y)^{2}}$$
$$\ \big((u-x)x'+(v-y)y'\big)^2-(u-x)^2-(v-y)^2=0 $$
$$(u-x)^2 (x')^2+2(u-x)x'(v-y)y'+(v-y)^2(y')^2-(u-x)^2-(v-y)^2=0$$
$$(u-x)^2\big((x')^2-1\big)+(v-y)^2\big((y')^2-1\big)+2(u-x)x'(v-y)y'=0$$
$$-(u-x)^2(y')^2-(v-y)(x')^2+2(u-x)x'(v-y)y'=0$$
$$[(u-x)y'-(v-y)x']^2=0 \Rightarrow (u-x)y'-(v-y)x'=0$$
How do you proceed from here to simplify the DE?

Comment: Of course, you mean the *speed* of the cat is $1$. Velocity is a vector. Your dot product equation loses information. Did you try writing down directly the condition that $c'$ and $m-c$ are parallel vectors?

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course that is why the dot product is equal to 1

Comment: You didn't stop to think about my question, did you? You get more information if you write down what I said.

Comment: Oh, I guess you got there eventually. With a typo. Do you have specific $u,v$?

Comment: @TedShifrin No you should be able to derive it for any function u or v and what typo?

Comment: You're missing a prime on the $x$ in your final equation. In general, I don't see how you're going to solve this. You can separate variables in the case that $u,v$ are constant.